# Compare database differences and get SQL output

Tags: mysql, sql, database, comparison, diff

I need ability to compare two similar databases. One will be slightly newer than the other and have changes to the structure of the database as well as possibly the content within it.

So far I have tried using liquibase but it doesn't seem to be comparing properly.
I have also tried the MySQL Diff Perl module which works but doesn't consider content.

**Main Question:**

Does anyone know any solutions that will give back SQL for both structural and content differences and generate a SQL script?

**A bit more info:**

The intended use for this is when making updates and installing MODs to phpBB so that the forum can be included in the build process along with the rest of our website. Which has a 4 tier process (local, development, staging, production).

When installing the phpBB updates and MODs I will make a dump of the current production database and lock the site so no new data can be added whilst I make changes. That way databases shouldn't come out of sync.

When installing MODs and updates sometimes the database structure changes and also the data within tables, especially when adding things requiring extra permissions etc.

The solution I use therefore will be used to compare the local database with the upgraded changes to the production database, providing me with a script I can run on each tier in the build process, rather than manually installing the update/MOD on each.

Comment: Enterprise Elements Repository has this functionality, but the tool is not free.

Comment: Will one database contain all the data from the other database? If so, is there an identifier you can use to compare similar records such as an immutable primary key?

Comment: Red Gate has both SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare, but unfortunately not free either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found a way to do it via [Navicat for MySQL](http://download.cnet.com/Navicat-MySQL-GUI/3000-10254_4-10071792.html) using the Tools > Structure Syncronization option.

This will give SQL statements for differences in structure between the two databases.

Then do do the data differences you can use Data Syncornization.

I've managed to copy out the SQL script for differences in structure. However the data syncronization seems to be more of an internal Navicat thing. I'm sure there's a way that the queries could be extracted though.

Please note I'm using a license version so not sure if its available in the free to use one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) Database synchronization tool to sync two databases,either one-way or two-way. By far this is the best data comparison tool for MySQL GUI. And, Schema sync for schema comparisons between two databases.

Both tools can generate SQL scripts.

Comment: Okay... I'll give those a try.